# What does the "d" symbol stand for in the list of the methods applicable for some object?

Tags: java, eclipse

Can anybody tell me what does the "d" symbol mean next to the green circle in the method description in eclipse?

I believe it is something like "deprecated" because I am using java 1.8 and I noticed that the same code cannot be compiled in java 1.7. As far as I know the deprecated methods are represented by declaration + a line over it.

Screenshot is attached for more details. Sorry if the question is duplicated.
Thank you![image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It describes methods that have [`default` implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), since Java 8.